# Javascript object with split key pattern to array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have below object :

```js
var obj = {
 a-0-first : 'value1',
 a-0-second : 'value2',
 a-1-first: 'value3',
 a-1-second: 'value4'         
 }
```

I want this :

```
a : [
  {
    fisrt : 'value1',
    second: 'value2'
  },
  {
    fisrt : 'value3',
    second: 'value4'
  }
]
```

How can I convert the object in JavaScript?

Comment: Where's your research/attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const transform = (obj) =>
    Object.entries(obj)
        .reduce((acc, [k,v], _, __, {k1, k2, k3} = parseK(k)) =>
            ((acc[k1] || (acc[k1] = [])),
             (acc[k1][k2] || (acc[k1][k2] = {})),
             (acc[k1][k2][k3] = v), acc), {})

const parseK = (k) => 
    ({groups: {k1, k2, k3}} = /^(?<k1>[^\-]*)-(?<k2>[^\-]*)-(?<k3>[^\-]*)/.exec(k), { k1, k2, k3 })

var obj = {
    "a-0-first": 'value1',
    "a-0-second": 'value2',
    "a-1-first": 'value3',
    "a-1-second": 'value4',
    "b-0-first": 'value5',
}

console.log(transform(obj))
```